# What's wrong with this async function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await

```
async lsEntered(){
  if(this.service.wd == '')
    {
      await basic((this.service.wd));
    }
    else
    {
      await basic(('/'+this.service.wd));
    }

    this.files = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FILENAMES'));

    var filesList = document.getElementById(this.trackLine.toString());
    var li;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.files[i].name));
    filesList.appendChild(li);
  }

  localStorage.clear();

}
```

I want to wait until basic is finished and JSON.parse finishes before displaying the values in the DOM. I'm getting the values of the previous call every time which is tell me the async is no working. To be fair I don't have tons of TS experience.

Edit: This is basic I was hoping not to have to deal with it as it's a javascript function and fragily integrated into this app.

```
var basic = function (path) {
    var ACCESS_TOKEN = '';
    var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });
    dbx.filesListFolder({ path: path })
        .then(function (response) {
        localStorage.setItem('FILENAMES',JSON.stringify(response.entries));
        console.log(response);
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is an error in `basic`.

Comment: basic is a JS function calling on an API I don't really want to mess with it.

Comment: You are not returning a promise in `basic`

Comment: you need to return the `filesListFolder` promise in `basic` to be able to `await`

Comment: You might want to invalidate that access token, now that everybody can see it on the edit history

Comment: `JSON.parse` does not return a promise, so you should omit the `await` there

Comment: Instead of storing the result in the localstorage, you should resolve the promise with it. That would make `basic` much more flexible to use.

Comment: Ok I invalidated the token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // Work you want to execute
  resolve("I am done");
});

myPromise.then((successMessage) => {
  // successMessage is whatever we passed in the resolve(...) function above.

  console.log("Yay! " + successMessage);
});
```

Comment: Where and how do I use promise? I'm new to this game.

Comment: Pretty helpful but I think I need to divide the code into three parts. How can I add another myPromise.then it's shooting compile errors when I try to add a third.

Comment: Try create an array of promises you use promise.all(). You'll find in this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 3):

You can only `await` promises<sup>1</sup> and `basic` is not returning a promise. You need to do

```
return dbx.filesListfolder(...)...
```

Also consider what [Bergi said in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851840/whats-wrong-with-this-async-function/45851921#comment78661946_45851840).

---

1: Actually, you can `await` any value, but there is no point in `await`ing something that is not a promise. By *not* returning the promise from `basic`, `lsEntered` won't wait for the local storage to be set.

Comment: Do I need to declare this return of dbx.filesListFolder as a promise somewhere?

Comment: I spent 3 hours trying to work with the typings and decided on doing this instead :(